# Handling NoneType in len() while in a Python lambda expression?

Tags: python, lambda, python-2.4

From what I understand, Python lambda's only allow expressions, not statements. I have a case where I an using `len()` in a lambda expression and am trying to get the length of the return value of a function call.  However, that function call has the potential to return `None`, which breaks `len()`.  Is there a graceful way around this?

Example:

```
def foo(obj_list, field):
    return maxk(obj_list, key=lambda obj: len(nested_getattr(obj, field)))
```

In the above, `maxk()` is a version of `max()` that accepts a `key` argument.  I'm on Python 2.4 (and cannot use anything higher at present), so I have a custom implementation of `max()` that takes a key argument, sourced [from here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/37337-key-argument-max) (refer to posts #140122 and #140143).  `nested_getattr()` is another utility function that acts like `getattr()` but can fetch an attribute nested within another.  That can be sourced [from here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/830134-getattr-nested-attributes#post3315464).

What the example function does (this is the actual function I am using with variables/names changed) is go through a list of objects (`obj_list`) and compare the length of the value in `field` and returns the object in the list whose `field` is the largest overall.

However, if the attribute specified in `field` for each object returns `None`, then `len()` will choke with a `TypeError`.  I think I could get around this using an inline conditional, but I would have to call `nested_getattr()` twice, once for the check, and possibly a second time if its return value is not `None`.  I would rather like to cache its return value to a variable and run that on a conditional before deciding what to return (or just have the generator expression skip over it entirely).

What's a good way to handle this?  I am open to other implementations of this function, `maxk()`, or `nested_getattr()` (if need be).

Comment: doesnt max accept a key also?  `max([1,2,3],key=lambda x:4-x)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: not in Python 2.4, I don't think, which is what the OP is constrained to use.

Comment: Not in the Python 2.4 version, it doesn't.  See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define the function separately as a regular function and then pass it into the maxk:

```
def getLen(obj):
    val = nested_getattr(obj, field)
    if val is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return len(val)
return maxk(obj, key=getLen)
```

Lambdas are meant to be used when it is easier to write an inline single-expression function that it would be to write a separate function.  If it becomes harder to think of how to write the lambda than to just write a normal function, just write a normal function.  There's no point spending time how to fit it into a lambda, because the lambda doesn't gain you anything in that case.

Edit: Lambdas are bytecode-identical to non-lambda functions that do the same thing.

```
>>> f = lambda x: x**2
>>> def g(x):
...     return x**2
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_POWER        
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_POWER        
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Agreed - lambdas are a tool generally left alone unless it's a really simple thing. Python functions are objects, just use ``def`` and make it easier and clearer. This could also use the ternary operator for brevity: ``return 0 if val is None else len(val)``.

Comment: +1.  Originally I was proposing `key=lambda obj: len(nested_getattr(obj, field) or []))`, but that's not as general (really only works for 0) and your point about `lambda` is a good one.

Comment: Yeah, the lambda expression WAS pretty simple and worked fine until I made other changes that necessitated having to deal with NoneTypes.  Basically trying to see if I can retain the use of the lambda whilst dealing with the NoneType at the same time.

Comment: That said, I thought lambdas were faster because they're evaluated by the C core like a generator expression?  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Lattyware: Can't use the ternary form because I am locked to Python 2.4 and it doesn't have that feature.

Comment: @Kumba Clarity should always be more important than speed unless it's a proven bottleneck in your application, and as to the ternary operator, it's just a little shorter, it's nothing important.

Comment: @Kumba: You are wrong.  Lambdas are no different than any other Python functions.  (I edited my answer with an example showing identical bytecode for an example function.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this:

```
lambda val: len(val or [])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the third argument to `nested_getattr()` with the same meaning as the third argument of `getattr()`:

```
len(nested_getattr(obj, field, ''))
```

Also *in this particular case* `len(nested_getattr(obj, field) or ''))` (suggested by @DSM) works fine if possible returned values are sequences and `None`.

In general a named function such as suggested by @BrenBarn might be preferable.

Comment: I think @BrenBarn's named function is the way to go, due to clarity.  The `len()` call is usually checking the length of a string attribute, though in my objects, it has a chance of being another object that implements __len__ as well.  I may use your idea of modifying `nested_getattr` as well in case that third argument is applicable in a different situation.

Comment: @Kumba: I've replaced `[]` with `''`. It doesn't change the result but it might be more readable in the context of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(obj_list, field):
    return maxk(obj_list, key=lambda obj: len(nested_getattr(obj, field) or []))
```

I can't test on 2.4 right now, but this works in 3.2.